# mergExt - How to have mergStoragePath to point to internal storage on Android?

Tags: android, livecode

I'm using mergStoragePath("pictures") to get the path where to save pictures on Android. It works fine when the SD card is present but in a devices without an SD card, it points anyway to:

/mnt/sdcard/Pictures

Is there a way to get to have mergStoragePath to point to internal storage?

Answer (score 1):

Not at present. The function is for external storage paths.